# Embedded terminal startup script

Tags: bash, terminal, phpstorm

I usually use bash scripts to setup my environments (mostly aliases that interact with Docker), ie:

```sh
# ops-setup.sh
#!/bin/bash

PROJECT_NAME="my_awesome_project"
PROJECT_PATH=`pwd`/${BASH_SOURCE[0]}
WEB_CONTAINER=${PROJECT_NAME}"_web_1"
DB_CONTAINER=${PROJECT_NAME}"_db_1"
alias chroot_project="cd $PROJECT_PATH"
alias compose="chroot_project;COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=$PROJECT_NAME docker-compose"
alias up="compose up -d"
alias down="compose stop;compose rm -f --all nginx web python"
alias web_exec="docker exec -ti $WEB_CONTAINER"
alias db="docker exec -ti $DB_CONTAINER su - postgres -c 'psql $PROJECT_NAME'"
# ...
```

I'd like them to be run when I open the embedded terminal.

I tried [Startup Tasks](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/startup-tasks.html) but they are not run in my terminal contexts.

Since I have a dedicated script for each of my projects, I can't run them from `.bashrc` or other.

How can I get my aliases **automatically** set at terminal opening ?

---

Today I'm running `. ./ops-setup.sh` manually each time I open a new embedded terminal.

Comment: Save them in a file e.g. `~/foobar.sh` and from `~/.bashrc` do `source ~/foobar.sh`

Comment: @heemayl, doesn't that have pretty much the same effect as putting it directly into .bashrc, which he doesn't want to do?

Comment: @LasseMeyer In effect, yes (thats what he needs), in implementation, different (you just source the file you need, clean).

Comment: @heemayl I don't really see the difference. How do I manage the conflicting  aliases between projects ? I guess you are not suggesting to modify `.bashrc` before opening each project :)

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY if thie **[urgent, three years old feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117946)** relates to your issue, i would ask you (kindly) to join your vote for it , and invite your friends to do the same. Seems to be the only thing that has any hope of getting Jetbrains product managers to stop their hibernation.

Comment: Nice catch, this feature would indeed answer to my question, Voted

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alias in your .bashrc file like so:

```
alias ops-setup='bash --init-file <(echo '. /home/test/ops-setup.sh'; echo '. /home/test/.bashrc')'
```

If you call ops-setup, it will open up a new bash inside your terminal, and source .bashrc like it normally would, as well as your own script.

The only way I see to completely automate this is to modify the source code of your shell, e.g. bash, and recompile it. The files that are sourced are hardcoded into the source code.